# $.inArray not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, arraylist

i am having a problem regarding storing objects into array. But when i try to check the existence of object using $.inArray, it always returns -1. i am using angularjs.

```
<input name="{{question.number}}"
            ng-click="radioSelected(question.choiceOneWeight, question.number,question.tmiGroup)"
            type="radio" value="{{question.choiceOneWeight}}" />



$scope.radioSelected = function(choice, question, tmiGroup) {
        var answer = {};
        answer.questionNumber = question;
        answer.answerWeight = choice;
        answer.tmiGroup = tmiGroup;

        if($.inArray(answer,userAnswers) < 0){
            userAnswers.push(answer);
        }
    };
```

my generated answer object is

```
{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"}
```

if i click on radio button multiple times,

userAnswers array looks like :

```
[{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"},
{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"},


{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"},

{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"},

{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"},

{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"},

{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"},

{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"},

{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"},

{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"},

{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"},

{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"},

{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"},

{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"},

{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"},

{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"},

{"questionNumber":23,"answerWeight":1,"tmiGroup":"JP"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use **[`inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)** for comparing anything that is not comparable using a simple `===`

For example:

```
var a = [{x: 1}];
$.inArray({x: 1}, a); // => -1
```

In your case, you can store a JSON stringified version of each question in the array and then use `.inArray()` on that.

i.e.

```
var answer = JSON.stringify({
    questionNumber: question,
    answerWeight: choice,
    tmiGroup: tmiGroup
});

// now you can use inArray as 'answer' is nothing but a string (JSON)
if($.inArray(answer, userAnswers) < 0){
    userAnswers.push(answer);
}
```

Remember to do `JSON.parse()` when retrieving the questions back from `userAnswers`

Comment: Thanks for reply, what can i do to do this comparison.

Comment: @Shahzeb this solves your problem, but it is definitely not the correct Angular's way to do data binding.

Comment: @sza - Have never used angularjs myself. Hence the generic solution.

Comment: @sza thanks for mentioning. I used the json.stringify to compare my objects as json strings and offcourse i iterate though array using $.each instead of using $.inArray(). I stored the data as done in my original code, and kindly if you think that i am doing it wrong in my original code, please do guide me as i am new to angularjs too. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, objects are only considered equal to one another if they both reference the same object. In your case, although `answer` may have the exact same properties and values as an object in your array, it is a different object and therefore considered not equal.

You need to pass the exact object to the function:

```
$scope.radioSelected = function(answer) {
    if($.inArray(answer,userAnswers) < 0){
        userAnswers.push(answer);
    }
});
```

then

```
ng-click="radioSelected(question)"
```